# SVD of large matrix in python on aws using spark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, svd

I am migrating an application to AWS that requires the calculation of a large symmetric, positive-valued matrix, followed by an SVD/eigendecomposition to recover some key eigenvectors and eigenvalues.  The edge size of the matrix could be 100K or more, so I am looking for a distributed operator in Spark to perform the SVD faster than a straight scipy/numpy svd operator.  I am not making the assumption of sparsity.  Can someone advise on how to perform the SVD using Spark?

Comment: Not an answer (nothing to do with Spark), but this [MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694339/parallel-algorithms-for-svd) might help.

Comment: Take a look https://stanford.edu/~rezab/papers/linalg.pdf

Comment: What is your Spark version? SVD functionality has been [added in 2.2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.SingularValueDecomposition)

Answer (score 0):

Spark version 2.2.0 has a python api for singular value decomposition.

```
# convert your rdd into RowMatrix
rm = RowMatrix(data_rdd)
# if number of components you wish to retain is p then
svd = rm.computeSVD(p, True)
U = svd.U
S = svd.S
V = svd.V
```